# How to handle references properly in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm following a C# programming course in which we have 3 project in a solution.
Project A has dependencies on projects B and C.

We are creating a new project - D (totally empty), which also has dependencies on C and D.

Following the video step-by-step the lecturer deletes the dependencies from project A, and just makes a new dependence on project D.

In the provided video you can see it: https://youtu.be/H8mBsOYJf7M?t=4186
Sorry for the language...

However when I do this locally it doesn't work at all, nevertheless I am following really, really close what he is doing.

In the provided video you can see it

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Don't assume anyone else should spend time on watching a video from end to end.

Comment: You can see what I mean in about 90 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. Project A was using .NET Core 2.1, while the others used 2.2.
Thanks everyone!